# Users getting 404 when accepting my App invite - why?

Tags: facebook

After creating an iOS app on Facebook, I've tried sending out app invites to FB users. However, the invite directs them to the URL http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=175116205946673 which is just a 404 page.

I've tried connecting the app to a Community Page in the hope that the invite would send them there instead, but no luck. The app is not in sandbox mode.

I've seen this question asked before, but no solution worked for me. I can't tell the invite to direct users to my Community Page, my App Center page or just my iTunes store page - because I don't know how to manually set the target URL in an invite.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Facebook Developer Apps center` ,

make sure that `175116205946673` is your app ID and also check:

1.Is your application on? (not sandbox)

2.Is your application authorized?

Comment: The number is definitely the correct ID.

1. The app is not in sandbox.
2. I'm pretty new to this. What to you mean by authorized? It has not been approved for App center if that's what you mean (as I need this to work before I can launch the app). I don't see anything in the dev center hinting at an authorization process.

Comment: - sorry, I hit Enter too fast. 1 and 2 are answered now.

Comment: In `Select how your app integrates with Facebook` what you've selected and which details you put in?

Comment: I've selected Native iOS App.

I've entered:
 - iOS bundle ID as setup in App Store.
 - iPad app store ID (clicking 'go to iTunes store' in the dev center works, so that's correct)
 - iOS SSO and Native Deep Linking are enabled
 - I haven't entered anything in URL Scheme Suffix.

Comment: Maybe , a. `Country Restrictions – uncheck it`
b. `Age Restrictions – choose Anyone (13+)`?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/ _“User to User Requests [/App to User Requests] are only available for Canvas apps […] as accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.”_ – so unless you set up a canvas page for your app, you will not be able to use requests.